# Is it more safe to modify MD5 output?

Tags: hash, md5, password-encryption

As an ordinary method, I always used to save MD5 of passwords in database while there are many websites that decode the MD5 hashed data to its original data (using rainbow database).

I wonder if it is more safe to modify the output of MD5 function (e.g. omitting the last character of MD5 output to create a new hashed data)? or there is a logic behind the MD5 that makes is more safe than every modified version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this doesn't do much good to make your passwords more secure. It adds a bit of "security by obscurity", but when we hash passwords, we prepare for the case where the attacker knows the hashes and the algorithm.

The problem with MD5 in general and with derivations is, that they can be calculated ways too fast. With common hardware you can calculate [8Giga MD5/s](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance), which makes brute-forcing too easy. Todays password cracker tools do not only offer plain MD5 hashes, you can calculate also derivations, e.g. `md5(strtoupper(md5($pass)))` out of the box.

For a secure storing of passwords you need a slow hash function like BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt with a cost factor. Of course they should be salted with a unique salt per password.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider a different hashing algorithm instead?

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/most-secure-password-hash-algorithms

Comment: Thank you. But my exact question is that if modification of MD5 makes it more safe or not?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour - It just doesn't make sense to try to improve a very insecure scheme, when there are proofed good solutions to the problem.